# Running IPython after changing the filename of python.exe

Tags: python, windows, interpreter, ipython

If I rename the python interpreter from C:\Python27\python.exe to C:\Python27\python27.exe and run it, it will not complain.

But if I now try to run C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython.exe, it will fail to start because now the python interpreter has a different filename.

My question is: how do I configure IPython (ms windows) to start up a python interpreter which has a different filename than python.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
python27.exe c:\Python27\Scripts\ipython-script.py

Answer (score 1):

Try to find Python in windows registry and changes path to python. After that try to reinstall ipython.

Comment: nope... doesn't work. maybe i didn't changed the exact key, do you know which key needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a config file where you can change, but you may have to recompile Ipython and change the interpreter variables. But why do you need to rename it to python27.exe when it already is in a python27 folder?

Answer (score 0):

instead of renaming python.exe, make sure the path to the python you want to run is before the path to other pythons